# direct linking to nested bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

As the title suggests, I am looking for a solution to direct linking to nested bootstrap tabs, The "parent" or top level tab works fine with /page#tab_id
while the "child" or sub tab is activated but the top level tab is unchanged.

I have something like this

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
      <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">
            <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            <p>Tab 4 Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

linking to tab3 and tab4 does not work if tab2 is not active

Comment: What do you mean by "direct linking"?

Comment: <a href="link-to-page.html#tab4">link</a>

Comment: basically it will work fine if I first activate the "parent" and then the "child" but if I want to directly open the child then its a no go. I need to page to reload back to the same tab

Comment: So you have to write your own script to achieve that, Bootstrap doesn't support nested tabs.